# Download image via Jquery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

How to load image via ajax and make it show in div?

```
$("<div />").load("#{load_image_path}/"+$(this).attr("data-id"), function(data) { //IN WHICH FORMAT IT MUST BE GIVEN?
    $(".la-anim-10").removeClass("la-animate");
    $(".fullscreen").css("background", "url('#{load_image_path(13)}')"); //HOW IT MUST BE WRITTEN HERE?
    $(".fullscreen").css("display", "block");
  });
```

Comment: the page you're trying to load... do you need that to be a full query string or is just passing the id okay?  does it need to be `/ID=123` or is just `/123` okay?  also... `data` is your response... I wouldn't know how you should use it unless you tell me what kind of response you're expecting exactly.

Comment: `#{load_image_path}/"+$(this).attr("data-id")` - this string makes full URL to controller (Rails syntax), like: http://localhost/welcome/loadimage/13 (13 is ID).

Comment: And I cannot guess, which responce I need. I can pass or image itself as binary data, or link to image

Comment: well... make sure the URL is correct and inside the function add `console.log(data)` and see what you're getting back (if anything).  [this looks like a good example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4338083/623952) of what you're trying to do...