# jquery load image to div after clicking href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I know this has been asked many times here, actually I found plenty of questions, each of them with a very good answer, I also followed those answers, used the different ways I found but I still don't get it to work.

What I'm trying to do is to load an image into a div, after clicking a link, instead of redirecting to a new page.

I'm using Pure Css (http://purecss.io/) to create a menu, the menu is made of a list, and each list item has a link inside it, like so:

```
<div class="pure-menu pure-menu-open" id="vertical-menu">
     <a class="pure-menu-heading">Models</a>
     <ul id="std-menu-items">
         <li class="pure-menu-heading cat">Menu heading</li>
         <li><a href="path_to_image"  class="model-selection">Model 1</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

In that same html file, I have another div where I want to load the image:

```
<div id="model-map"></div>
```

I've tried the following ways, using jquery, in a separate js file:

I followed the selected answer for this question, which seemed to have the best approach ([Can I get the image and load via ajax into div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337917/can-i-get-the-image-and-load-via-ajax-into-div))

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("ready"); //this shows on console
    $('.model-selection').click(function () {
        console.log("clicked"); //this doesn't show after clicking
        var url = $(this).attr('href'),
        image = new Image();
        image.src = url;
        image.onload = function () {
            $('#model-map').empty().append(image);
        };
        image.onerror = function () {
            $('#model-map').empty().html('That image is not available.');
        }

        $('#model-map').empty().html('Loading...');

        return false;
    });
});
```

As you see, the console.log("clicked") never executes, I'll be ashamed if it's something stupid, cause it seems that the function is not handling the click event properly.
I get the image of course, but in a new page (default behavior of clicking the href) and I want it to load on the div without being redirected. I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance!

## Edit

The code above is working, and both answers are correct, the issue was due to some code inside  tags in my html ( YUI code to create the dropdowns for the menu) and it was conflicting with my js file. I moved it to the actual js file and now it works as expected.
Thanks!

Comment: use the html5 file api to read the image binary directly from the file input into a base64 data uri, which you can then set as the src attribute for the image. its pretty easy. google it

Answer (score 2):

You need to use event.stopPropagation();

```
$('.model-selection').click(function( event ) {

    event.stopPropagation();
    // add your code here

});
```

Comment: Thanks!, as I said to Spencer, I tried with both preventDefault and stopPropagation, but I'm still being redirected to a new page. I think there may be something wrong with my code, but haven't found the error yet

Comment: did u see if you get any error on your console? there might be some error that makes jQuery fail

Comment: jsfiddle.net/jdelva/zsm4zqk8/1 
no errors so far, it works on jsfiddle, 
I'm looking at every inch of my html and js files to see WTF is going on

Comment: did u add the code above inside this? $(document).ready(function () { });

Comment: yes sir, I found out the error, I had some code from the YUI framework inside my html inside <script> tags, and it was conflicting with my js file. I left them there cause I was testing some it with the menu (it creates the dropdown menus for Pure Css). I moved them to the actual js file, and that's it. Either way, thanks for helping me, I gave your answer an up vote cause it was usefull

Answer (score 1):

You just need to prevent the default behavior of moving to a new page for `<a>` tags, to do this say `e.preventDefault()` first:

```
...
$('.model-selection').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Stops the redirect
    console.log("clicked"); // Now this works
    ...
)};
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried using preventDefault and also stopPropagation but I'm still being redirected to a new page. What may be wrong?

Comment: @dlvx Did you add the `function (e)`?

Comment: yes sir, followed your answer, but still doesn't work, so I think it may be something else with my code

Comment: @dlvx That's odd. The `return false` alone should be preventing the redirect. The only thing I can think of is you might not be clicking the element with the class `.model-selection`, or the old page is getting brought up in cache. Or maybe there is an error in your code or loading jQuery (check the console). Is it possible you could re-create this problem using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jdelva/zsm4zqk8/1/
There it is, and it works, I removed some list items cause the menu is bigger that that, what is strange is that with all the list items it doesn't work, but it works with less items. What I don't know right now is if it is a problem with my html, maybe some tags. I will have to look closer at it.