# images not displaying through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

ok here is the full code

chenging the background image css property through jquery and the images are not displaying .... checked the paths and they are ok

divs exist, css is ok , paths are ok, images exist BUT it works on the on.show function and it does not work on the click function

```
    // when new category show default images
    $('#newCategory').on('show.bs.modal', function () {

        var category = "<?php echo $_SESSION['home-url']; ?>" + 'admin/images/categories/profiles/default.png';
        var banner = "<?php echo $_SESSION['home-url']; ?>" + 'admin/images/categories/banners/default.png';

        $( '#categoryPreview' ).css( { backgroundImage: 'url(' + category + ')' } );
        $( '#bannerPreview' ).css( { backgroundImage: 'url(' + banner + ')' } );
    });       


    // load category info before display dialog
    $('body').on('click', '.btn-upd-id',function(){        

        var id = $(this).attr('upd-id');

        $("#update-category-id").val(id);

        if( id != "" ){ 
            $.post('category/category_info.php', {id: id}, function(data){
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);

                $("#upd-name").val(obj[0].name);

                var category = "<?php echo $_SESSION['home-url']; ?>" + 'admin/images/categories/profiles/' + obj[0].category_image;

                var banner = "<?php echo $_SESSION['home-url']; ?>" + 'admin/images/categories/banners/' + obj[0].banner_image;                    

                $( '#updCategoryPreview' ).css( { backgroundImage: 'url(' + category + ')' } );
                $( '#updBannerPreview' ).css( { backgroundImage: 'url(' + banner + ')' } );       
            })
        }       
    });
```

HTML

```
                                <!-- category image -->
                                <div class="row">          
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="category">Category Image</label>
                                            <br/>
                                            <div id="updCategoryPreview"></div>  
                                            <input type="file" class="img" id="upd-category" name="upd-category">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                      
                                <!-- banner image -->        
                                <div class="row">                                                
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="banner">Category Banner</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <div id="updBannerPreview"></div>
                                            <input type="file" class="img" id="upd-banner" name="upd-banner">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

I expect it to load the image but it displays nothing.

Comment: have you inspect the page with developer tools.

Comment: @lef please show me the result for category and banner

Comment: @ShahzadKhan the result is the full path to the image

Comment: use below code.
$('#updCategoryPreview').css('background-image', 'url(' + category + ')');
$('#updBannerPreview').css('background-image', 'url(' + banner + ')');

Comment: May be you have some syntax issue that's way not showing the images.

Comment: @ChinthakaFernando yes but says nothing

Comment: @ShahzadKhan tried it ... not working

Comment: just updated the source code included for anyone to help ... thank you

Comment: Could you provide the HTML? And did you check that you have exaclty one element with `id="updCategoryPreview"` and one with `id="updBannerPreview"`?

The id selector won't work for multiple elements with the same ID

Comment: @gearsdigital added the html .... no duplicated exist

Answer (score 1):

fed up
used this piece of code and its working

```
image = new Image();
image.src = url;
image.onload = function () {
    $('#image-holder').empty().append(image);
};
```

found here
[Can I get the image and load via ajax into div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337917/can-i-get-the-image-and-load-via-ajax-into-div)

thank you all for your help